# Should I check if a vector is empty before I use std::transform

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

Would it be a good idea to check if a vector is empty or not before using `std::transform` and `back_inserter` or could nothing wrong happen since the `vector.begin()` will be the same as `vector.end()` and will not insert nothing in the new vector ?

Comment: Probably not,, if you use an optimizing compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -O -g`...)

Comment: What kind of searching did you do?

Comment: Not just `std::transform`, but every algorithm function I can think of doesn't require a check for `empty()`, and will just work as expected.  There are `vector` functions, such as `pop_back`, or accessing element `[0]`, where you need to check for empty, but no algorithm functions (unless there is one I missed).

Comment: No. It would be like checking if an array is empty (a size of zero) before a `for-loop`: `for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is unneeded.  If `empty()` is `true`, then `begin() == end()` and `transform` will become a non-op as it works in the range `[begin, end)`

Comment: [For details see the possible implementations linked here.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform#Possible_implementation)

Answer (score 6):

All `std` algorithms are noops on empty containers.  The only kind that are an issue is something like `std::minmax(std::initializer_list)`, which requires it be non-empty; it doesn't return an iterator, but instead elements.

(Note that in that case, it takes a list, which is usually right there in `{}`, so it is usually obvious if it is empty.)

The only reason you'd test for empty prior to calling them should be:

1. You are about to do many such algorithms in a row on the data.
2. You want to be able to easily detect, with an assert or a break point or log, being passed an empty container.
3. There is some difference in how you handle empty data other than "do nothing" (note: this is often, but not always, a sign of a flaw in your design).